# JQUERY - Load em formulário com editor

Tags: jquery

É possível ao jogar um texto todo desalinhado e cheio de espaços a esquerda, em cima e em baixo. Deixar ele todo alinhado e sem espaços?

Por exemplo:

```
    
       texto
texto
texto texto
         texto
```

e sair assim, tudo sem espaços e alinhado a esquerda:

```
texto
texto
texto texto
texto
```

Isso já automático ao colar no editor (textarea).

Comment: Man vc consegue remover os espaços em branco com a função replace(' ', '') do javascript.. e pode adicionar classes CSS para formatar o conteúdo.. seria legal postar seu código, oque vc fez até agora para que possa te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando jQuery, pode ser assim:

```js
$("textarea#txt1").on('input',function(){
  var txt = $(this).val();
  var txt_novo = txt.replace(/(^|[\n\r])([\t\s])+/g, "$1");
  $(this).val(txt_novo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txt1" style="width:350px; height: 250px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Era isso cara, que beleza. Valeuuuu

Comment: uma pergunta de leigo, já uso esse código no header do site <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"> mas não funcionou, só com esse cdn que vc enviou. Porque?

Comment: Não consigo fazer funcionar local. Não sei onde posto o código aqui, ainda não entendi o stackoverflow

Comment: to fazendo tudo igualzinho.

Comment: algumas coisas aconteceram. Só consegui colocando a função dentro do body, no header não vai. E uso fckeditor, ai complicou tudo. No textarea ta funcionando.

Comment: Legal! Você pode tentar colocar dentro de um $( document ).ready(function() {...}); no header pra ele bindar o input depois que a página carregou! Quanto ao editor, ai vc vai ter que verificar se ele não tem algum pré-processador de copiar e colar!

Comment: coloquei antes do fechmento do body, estranho, só funciona assim. O fckeditor vai ser foda, mas valeu.

Comment: Valeu @Rod! Se foi útil, marca a resposta ai como solução! Bons estudos!

Comment: como faz isso? rs